# "Invalid Array Length" when running mocha tests with --reporter Progress

Tags: mocha.js

When running my unit tests with the --reporter Progress option I'm getting an error as below. When I remove the reporter option, all tests complete fine.

```
RangeError: Invalid array length
    at Runner.<anonymous> (\node_modules\mocha\lib\reporters\progress.js:80:26)
    at Runner.emit (events.js:412:35)
    at \node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:604:14
    at done \node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:319:5)
    at \node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:377:11
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:6280) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
(node:6280) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example